# how to save the data with same document id in 2 different collection in firestore android studio java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store the data in with same document id in 2 different collection in firestore firebase?

i have try this one but i did't understand the code.

FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

// Get the document from the first collection

DocumentReference sourceDocumentRef = firestore.collection("collection1").document("documentId");

sourceDocumentRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {

```
if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

    // Create a new document in the second collection with the same data

    firestore.collection("collection2").document("documentId").set(documentSnapshot.getData())

            .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {

                // Document successfully copied

            })

            .addOnFailureListener(e -> {

                // Error copying document

            });
} else {

    // Document does not exist in the first collection

}
```

})

.addOnFailureListener(e -> {

```
// Error retrieving document
```

});

This is the simple code of my project

db.collection("measurements")
.document(RoundTxt)
.set(measurementData)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Measurement Added ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_newUserTab_to_oldUserTab);
}
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

```
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to Added Measurement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Try using [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to write to multiple collections.

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo